# targeting AWS services locally

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was wondering if its possible to target the services of aws, for example, dynamoDB, from outside of aws, for example, code that runs on my personal computer.
All I could find is creating a mock of dynamodb localy and configuring to it, but not a way to configure the code to target the real thing.
Thanks.

By target I mean to use only the sdk of the language to access the service, not some kind of rest api.

Comment: AWS services reside on the Internet. They can be accessed from any computer on the Internet. The best way to access services is to [use an SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk). The SDK will always access the "real thing", but you will need to provide a valid set of credentials. Is this different to how you have been accessing AWS?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after more search, and as @JohnRotenstein recommended, I have searched for a way to configure the credentials.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html

The link above shows how to configure all the needed credentials.
Of course there is an IAM user with a key and secret key.

Cheers.